# Is it possible to get the value of NUnit custom attribute PropertyAttribute via reflection?

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-3.0

I have something like the following

```
[TestFixture]
public class Test
{
    [Test]
    [Property("Test", "TEST-1234")]
    public void TestOne()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }

    [Test]
    [Property("Test", "TEST-5678")]
    public void TestTwo()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }
}
```

I need to get the value of the attribute `Test` i.e I need to get `TEST-1234` via reflection. I know that  it's possible to get it at runtime with something like `TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties["Test"])` but that doesn't help me.

I've tried several methods like

```
test.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NUnit.Framework.PropertyAttribute)).ToList()[0]
```

which gets me the attribute object itself but I cannot access the value itself, is this possible?

Comment: Sure it's possible, but we need a bit more info here. If you don't want to get it at runtime through the `TestContext`, how and where do you want to get it? Answer will vary accordingly.

Comment: @Charlie I'm working in a console app that essentially executes `nunit3-console.exe` and then posts results to a tracking system. For those purposes I need to extract the issue number from a specified method (TestCase) which is decorated with the `Property` attribute. I'm loading the `dll` and extract the methods and get the attributes via `GetCustomAttributes` for instance but I can't see a way to get the value from the "Test" property. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

So, let's assume you have an array of property attributes, found on a given method. You got them by reflection specifying the type `PropertyAttribute` so you know that's what they are, even though the array is `Attribute[]`.

So you need to find all attributes (or the first attribute if you just want one) with a `Name` property of "Test" as well as the value assigned to that property.

[BTW, "Test" seems a pretty bad name to me here, since NUnit has so many things called "Test" and your own test code probably does as well. But we will stay with that name for the example.]

You need to do something like this...

```
for each (PropertyAttribute attr in attrs) // attrs filled by you already
{
     if (attr.Name == "Test")
         testValue = attr.Value;

     // Process the value as you want. If there's just one and this is in
     // a function call, you can return it. If you are doing something else,
     // do it here and then `break` to exit the loop
}
```

You can do it with less code using `System.Linq`, but I think the loop will help you see more clearly what has to be done.

Comment: I tried this before but unfortunately PropertyAttribute, which is a NUnit construct does not contain `Name` or `Value` properties.

Comment: Seems kinda clunky but what did work was `attribute.Properties["Test"][0]`

Comment: Yes, sorry... that was "forum code"... fwiw `PropertiesAttribute` started out with one name and value but was improved so that one attribute can carry several different properties and each can have multiple values internally... from which you get the strange syntax.

Comment: Also, the usual warning applies... you are using an internal implementation detail, which has changed before and might change again.